# Suspending a for loop, then resuming it to background prevent it from iterating further

Tags: for-loop, zsh, jobs

Suspending a `for` loop (using Ctrl-Z), then resuming it with `bg` specifically, will prevent it from iterating to the next instance. The `for` loop still finishes the current iteration, but just stops there. The issue happens when sending the job to background only. No issue when using `fg`.

Running in a subshell does not even help.

Context:

```bash
$ (for f in *.webm; do ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i "$f" -map 0 -s hd1080 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -b:a 64k "${f%.webm}".mp4 > /dev/null 2>&1; done)
```

Is there a way to allow the `for` loop to complete till the end after suspending/resuming to the background?

Comment: Probably a typo, but the loop in your post does not have a closing `done`. I have not been able to reproduce this on my system, with a simpler loop: `for f in *.webm; do; print ${f:r}.mp4; sleep 2; done`. The process continues in the background after issuing the `bg` command.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected. I ran your command as well, and it just works fine. However, the issue still persists with FFmpeg. I don't understand why it's such a problem with FFmpeg.

Comment: I did further tests. Combining `for` loop with FFmpeg simply doesn't work with pausing/resuming it with `bg` command. Simple example: `(for f in *.m(kv|p4); do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vn -c:a copy ${f%.m(kv|p4)}.aac 2> ffmpeg.log; sleep 3; done`

Comment: On my system, `ffmpeg` was pausing to ask if the output should be overwritten, even though `-n` is supposed to prevent that. This seemed to work, both with `fg` and `bg`: `for f in *.mp4; do print $f; ffmpeg -i $f -y -c:a copy $f:r.aac &> $f:r.log; sleep 2; done`. I tweaked the code a bit so the log wasn't overwritten in the loop; `$f:r` is the filename without the extension, `&>` redirects both stdout and stderr.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. After issuing your command it still only works with `fg` on my end.